# How make file path work on different OS languages VB NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, filepath

I have an application which looks for some files on the local disk of the computer.

Ex.: `...AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\ro.medina\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\FormatoSemanal\FormatoSemanal\Database1.mdf;...`

Now, the OS on my computer is English therefore the route `C:\Users\ro.medina\Documents...` works fine But, in a Spanish OS the route would be.. `C:\Usuarios\ro.medina\Documentos...`

Since it's a specified string I don't see how to make it go to the Documents Folder on whatever OS language it's on. My solution so far is to hardcode a folder con the C like this: `C:\CodedFolder\LookupFiles` but I would like to know if there's another way around to this

Thanks in advance

Comment: The English folder names exist on other OS languages as well, afaik.

Comment: `Environment` class has methods to get any of those folder names using the current culture.  Research `GetSpecialFolder` method

Comment: A localized name like C:\Usuarios\ is not actually a directory, it is a symbolic link to C:\Users.  Code will be fine as long as it doesn't run on XP.